# Position absolute not working on pseudo element in firefox 12+

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am having a problem with the positioning on a pseudo element in firefox 12+ (maybe earlier). The element looks as if relative to the page however I do have `position:relative` on the anchor tag. Any suggestions ?

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/test-file/Test-File/" rel="attachment wp-att-150">Test File</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a[rel~="attachment"] {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: #EAE3EA;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #515151;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 5px 0 47px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

a[rel~="attachment"]::before {
  content: '';
  background: url(img/file.png) no-repeat;
  width: 37px;
  height: 48px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Is it working in other browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using relative positioning you could use margins to position `a::before` keep in mind you can use negative margins so you have plenty of control over the element's positioning.

Comment: On this site you can accept answers by clicking the tick next to the vote rather than editing to [solved] ;)

Answer (score 1):

you overwrote

```
display: inline-block;
```

with

```
display: table-cell
```

maybe using display inline-block does the trick

Comment: Thanks for this, I did not use your answer in the end, but thanks for pointing out the duplicate :)